How to fix the name i does not exist in current context?
I am trying to spawn game objects randomly in unoccupied positions on my game board. I created a function to get unoccupied random positions. The code is throwing me an error...
int getRandPos()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            {
                i = Random.Range(0, 8);
                if (player[i] == Seed.EMPTY)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return i;
        }

Error:The name 'i' does not exist in the current context
I have initialised it with the int keyword, and used braces in the for loop,so why is there still and error? How can I fix it? Thank you very much
Edit: Code for my player object
public Seed[] player = new Seed[9];


please provide more information about player object. It might not be instantiated or your index is out of range, etc.

ok, ive just updated it! the player is instantiated cuzz it shows up in my inspector with 9 rows...

Just use return i;  instead of break;

The root cause is that i is initialized within the loop, so you can;t reference it outside of the loop. If you just want to find a random empty spot, you could just loop until you find one:
int getRandPos()
{
    int pos = -1;
    while(pos < 0)
    {
        i = Random.Range(0, 8);
        if (player[i] == Seed.EMPTY)
        {
            pos = i;
        }
    }
    return pos;
}

but this will loop infinitely if there is no open slot. Another option is to collect all of the empty slots and pick one at random:
int getRandPos()
{
    List<int> emptySlots = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        if (player[i] == Seed.EMPTY)
        {
            emptySlots.Add(i);
        }
    }
    return emptySlots[Random.Range(0, emptySlots.Count)];
}

I'll leave it to you to decide what to do if there are no empty slots...

thank you! it has finally worked:) with your second suggestion... for the last part, i had to use emptySlots.Count because I was getting the error: List' does not contain a definition for 'Length' and no accessible extension method 'Length' accepting a first argument of type 'List' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) But thank you very much and my game now works:))
